# Simple worker thread in C++ class

Tags: c++, multithreading, design-patterns, architecture, c++17

Assume that there is a class which contains some data and calculates some results given queries, and the queries take a relatively large amount of time.

An example class (everything dummy) is:

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <thread>

struct do_some_work
{
    do_some_work(std::vector<int> data) 
        : _data(std::move(data))
        , _current_query(0)
        , _last_calculated_result(0) 
    {}
    void update_query(size_t x) {
        if (x < _data.size()) {
            _current_query = x;
            recalculate_result();
        }
    }
    int get_result() const {
        return _last_calculated_result;
    }
private:
    void recalculate_result() {
        //dummy some work here     
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        _last_calculated_result = std::accumulate(_data.cbegin(), _data.cbegin() + _current_query, 0);
    }

    std::vector<int> const _data;
    size_t _current_query;
    int _last_calculated_result;
};
```

and this can be used in the main code like:

```
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    //make some dummy data
    std::vector<int> test_data(20, 0);
    std::iota(test_data.begin(), test_data.end(), 0);

    {
        do_some_work work(test_data);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < test_data.size(); ++i) {
            work.update_query(i);
            std::cout << "result = {" << i << "," <<  work.get_result() << "}" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

The above will wait in the main function a lot.

Now, assuming we want to run this querying in a tight loop (say GUI) and only care about about getting a "recent" result quickly when we query.

So, we want to move the work to a separate thread which calculates the results, and updates it, and when we get result, we get the last calculated one. That is, we want to change `do_some_work` class to do its work on a thread, with minimal changes (essentially find a pattern of changes that can be applied to (mostly) any class of this type).

My stab at this is the following:

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>

struct do_lots_of_work
{
    do_lots_of_work(std::vector<int> data) 
        : _data(std::move(data))        
        , _current_query(0)
        , _last_calculated_result(0)
        , _worker()
        , _data_mtx()
        , _result_mtx()
        , _cv()
        , _do_exit(false)
        , _work_available(false)
    {
        start_worker();
    }
    void update_query(size_t x) {
        {
            if (x < _data.size()) {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(_data_mtx);
                _current_query = x;
                _work_available = true;
                _cv.notify_one();
            }
        }        
    }
    int get_result() const {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(_result_mtx);
        return _last_calculated_result;
    }

    ~do_lots_of_work() {
        stop_worker();
    }

private:
    void start_worker() {
        if (!_worker.joinable()) {
            std::cout << "starting worker..." << std::endl;
            _worker = std::thread(&do_lots_of_work::worker_loop, this);
        }
    }

    void stop_worker() {
        std::cout << "worker stopping..." << std::endl;
        if (_worker.joinable()) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(_data_mtx);
            _do_exit = true;
            lck.unlock();
            _cv.notify_one();            
            _worker.join();
        }
        std::cout << "worker stopped" << std::endl;
    }

    void worker_loop() {
        std::cout << "worker started" << std::endl;
        while (true) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(_data_mtx);
            _cv.wait(lck, [this]() {return _work_available || _do_exit; });
            if (_do_exit) { break; }
            if (_work_available) {
                _work_available = false;
                int query = _current_query; //take local copy
                lck.unlock(); //unlock before doing lots of work.
                recalculate_result(query);                
            }
        }
    }

    void recalculate_result(int query) {
        //dummy lots of work here
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        int const result = std::accumulate(_data.cbegin(), _data.cbegin() + query, 0);    
        set_result(result);
    }

    void set_result(int result) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(_result_mtx);
        _last_calculated_result = result;
    }
    
    std::vector<int> const  _data;
    size_t                  _current_query;
    int                     _last_calculated_result;
    
    std::thread             _worker;
    mutable std::mutex      _data_mtx;
    mutable std::mutex      _result_mtx;
    std::condition_variable _cv;
    bool                    _do_exit;
    bool                    _work_available;
};
```

and the usage is (example):

```
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    //make some dummy data
    std::vector<int> test_data(20, 0);
    std::iota(test_data.begin(), test_data.end(), 0);

    {
        do_lots_of_work work(test_data);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < test_data.size(); ++i) {            
            work.update_query(i);
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
            std::cout << "result = {" << i << "," << work.get_result() << "}" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to work, giving the last result, not stopping the main function etc.

But, this looks a LOT of changes are required to add a worker thread to a simple class like `do_some_work`. Items like two `mutexes` (one for the worker/main interaction data, and one for the result), one `condition_variable`, one `more-work-available` flag and one `do-exit` flag, that is quite a bit. I guess we don't want an `async` kind of mechanism because we don't want to potentially launch a new thread every time.

Now, I am not sure if there is a MUCH simpler pattern to make this kind of change, but it feels like there should be. A kind of pattern that can be used to off-load work to a thread.

So finally, my question is, can `do_some_work` be converted into `do_lots_of_work` in a much simpler way than the implementation above?

### Edit (Solution 1) ThreadPool based:

Using a threadpool, the worker loop can be skipped, we need two mutexes, for result and query. Lock in updating query, Lock in getting result, Both lock in recalculate (take a local copy of a query, and write to result).

Note: Also, when pushing work on the queue, as we do not care about the older results, we can clear the work queue.

Example implementation (using the CTPL threadpool)

```
#include "CTPL\ctpl_stl.h"
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>

struct do_lots_of_work_with_threadpool
{
    do_lots_of_work_with_threadpool(std::vector<int> data)
        : _data(std::move(data))
        , _current_query(0)
        , _last_calculated_result(0)
        , _pool(1)
        , _result_mtx()
        , _query_mtx()
    {
        
    }
    void update_query(size_t x) {
        if (x < _data.size()) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(_query_mtx);
            _current_query = x;            
        }
        _pool.clear_queue(); //clear as we don't want to calculate any out-date results.
        _pool.push([this](int id) { recalculate_result(); });
    }
    int get_result() const {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(_result_mtx);
        return _last_calculated_result;
    }
private:
    void recalculate_result() {                
        //dummy some work here     
        size_t query;
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(_query_mtx);
            query = _current_query;
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        int result = std::accumulate(_data.cbegin(), _data.cbegin() + query, 0);
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(_result_mtx);
            _last_calculated_result = result;
        }
    }

    std::vector<int> const _data;
    size_t _current_query;
    int _last_calculated_result;

    ctpl::thread_pool _pool;
    mutable std::mutex _result_mtx;
    mutable std::mutex _query_mtx;
};
```

### Edit (Solution 2) With ThreadPool and Atomic:

This solution changes the shared variables to atomic, and so we do not need any mutexes and do not have to consider taking/releasing locks etc. This is much simpler and very close to the original class (of course assumes a threadpool type exists somewhere as it is not part of the standard).

```
#include "CTPL\ctpl_stl.h"
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>

struct do_lots_of_work_with_threadpool_and_atomics
{
    do_lots_of_work_with_threadpool_and_atomics(std::vector<int> data)
        : _data(std::move(data))
        , _current_query(0)
        , _last_calculated_result(0)
        , _pool(1)
    {

    }
    void update_query(size_t x) {
        if (x < _data.size()) {            
            _current_query.store(x);
        }
        _pool.clear_queue(); //clear as we don't want to calculate any out-date results.
        _pool.push([this](int id) { recalculate_result(); });
    }
    int get_result() const {        
        return _last_calculated_result.load();
    }
private:
    void recalculate_result() {
        //dummy some work here             
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        _last_calculated_result.store(std::accumulate(_data.cbegin(), _data.cbegin() + _current_query.load(), 0));                
    }

    std::vector<int> const _data;
    std::atomic<size_t> _current_query;
    std::atomic<int> _last_calculated_result;

    ctpl::thread_pool _pool;
};
```

Comment: https://github.com/vit-vit/ctpl

Comment: If you find a patters you like, you should decouple it from the class that holds the data and does the work. This seems ok as a proof of concept though.

Comment: Thank you @NikosC. Using a thread pool only solves the problem of setting up a thread, there still need to be synchronization for updating the result, so are you suggesting having a threadpool as a member of the class and a mutex to protect the result? Another point is that we only want the "latest" result, so we might have pushed a lot of work on the pool which we do not want, so I guess we clear the pool everytime before we push?

Comment: Thank you @super. Yes, I guess I am trying to find a simpler (pre-existing?) pattern for this kind of work.

Comment: @Akanksh No. Decouple! Use a thread pool instead of your `worker_loop`. The function you pass in to the thread pool needs access to mutexes or whatever you use for synchronization. Once you have a working pattern you can apply it to any class, by only adding the mutexes to it more or less.

Comment: @super Thank you. I have added a solution to the question above, using the threadpool. Much simpler, although care needs to be taken on when to lock and unlock the mutexes and to limit the amount the locks are taken for etc.

Comment: Seems like a great case for std::async